# Onmouseenter validation error

Tags: html, validation

When I tried to validate this code in https://validator.w3.org/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>onmouseenter validation</title>
</head>
<body>        
<div onmouseenter="javascript:alert('hello');">Event Validation</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The following error appears

> "Attribute onmouseenter not allowed on element div at this point."

Somebody know why the validator keeps telling is an error?

I believe that onmouseenter is a valid attribute for a html element.

Comment: Visual Studio (2012 PRO) also underlines the onmouseenter event saying it is not a valid attribute. They surely get their rules from w3 so it makes sense. It works perfectly fine though. Just like Mooseman mentioned - this is most likely a bug on their end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is perfectly valid. [The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#handler-onmouseenter) clearly states that `onmouseenter` is a valid event handler on *all* HTML elements in HTML5. There is no change in [the HTML 5.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#handler-onmouseenter) at the present time.

Substituting `onmouseover` produces no errors in the validator, leading me to believe this is merely a bug on their end. [This bug does not appear to have been reported](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=onmouseenter), so I would recommend [filing one](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/enter_bug.cgi?product=Validator).